# MYSQL Rounding off Questions

Tags: mysql

Which MySQL function should I use to get an output 34000 for the input value 34567.7896?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round()` with a negative second argument:

```
select round(val, -3)
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) is the documentation.